# C# Split array into fixed number of ranges

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, buffer

I have a byte[] array say of any length and i want to split it into parts and each part would have a length of 2205 and i would have to do operations on those 2205 bytes, here is my algorithm:

```
// SPLIT BY 2205 Bytes
int block = 2205;
int counter = 0;
byte[] to_Send = new byte[block];
foreach (byte b in ARCHIEVE_BUFFER)
{
    if (counter < 2205)
    {
        to_Send[counter] = b;
        counter++;
    }
    else if (counter == 2205)
    {
        // do some operation on those 2205 bytes which stored on the array to_send

        counter = 0;
        to_Send[counter] = b;
        counter++;
    }
}
```

I just wanna Split the array into fixed number of ranges

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: You may want to look into `Array.Copy`.

Comment: What is your question? I think your wording is confusing. The question title makes it sound like you want a fixed number of subsets but the question body makes it sounds like you want a fixed size for the subsets and as many as is necessary..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using linq you can split your array into `blocksize` bytes blocks

```
int count=0;
int blocksize = 2205;
List<List<byte>> blocks =  ARCHIEVE_BUFFER
                            .GroupBy( _ => count++ / blocksize)
                            .Select(x=>x.ToList())
                            .ToList();
```

Comment: Interesting code, but do you think that it will be performant? (Not that really matters here, but just to know)

Answer (score 1):

The class Array has a static method that copy from one array to another array starting from a position in both arrays and for a specified length

[Array.Copy(array1, pos1, array2, pos2, length)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z50k9bft.aspx)

```
int block = 2205;
int counter = 0;
byte[] to_Send = new byte[block];
Array.Copy(ARCHIEVE_BUFFER, 0, to_Send, 0, 2205);
```

It is unclear what you want to do with the `to_Send` array once is filled with the first block, however it should be easy to add a loop around the Array.Copy changing the starting position at every loop and use the new data extracted from the ARCHIEVE_BUFFER

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Array and use Buffer.BlockCopy for this.
Iterating over an Array and copying Byte per Byte is quiet inperformant.

```
byte[] toSend = null;
int Remaining = ARCHIEVE_BUFFER.Length;
int Packed = 0;

while(Remaining > 0){
   toSend = new byte[Remaining >= block ? block : Remaining];
   Buffer.BlockCopy(toSend, 0, ARCHIEVE_BUFFER, Packed, toSend.Length); // not sure about params
   Packed += toSend.Length;
   Remaining -= toSend.Length;

   // todo: send here
}
```

Comment: You can use Math.Min instead of the ternary.

Comment: Would be an easy readable way! I'm using the ternary very often (also in JavaScript) because it think that's faster than moving data around on the stack (or maybe heap or in the Registers) - depending on the way the Parameters are passed to the machine. I'm not sure how Math.Min is translated in IL - perhaps it's just reduced to a ternary.

Comment: It's the smallest optimization I've ever seen. Just use Math.Min.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.Copy` method or `Buffer.BlockCopy` as mentioned above. However, in performance critical situations, use `BlockCopy`.

```
Array.Copy(sourceArray, 0, destinationArray, 0, size);
```

or

```
Buffer.BlockCopy(sourceArray, 0, destinationArray, 0, size);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or another way again, by using [Enumerable.Skip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/bb358985.aspx) and [Enumerable.Take](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/bb503062.aspx):

```
//ARCHIEVE_BUFFER: source array 
//block: the size of slice
for(var i=0; i<ARCHIEVE_BUFFER.Length;i+=block) {
    var to_Send = ARCHIEVE_BUFFER.Skip(i).Take(block);
    ProcessSubArray(to_Send);
}
```